# focusout() jquery

Tags: jquery

**Добрый день**

Необходимо решить следующую проблему:

- есть ссылка, по нажатию на которую, она исчезает, а вместо нее появляется поле ввода;
- после ввода числа в данное текстовое поле и нажатию на enter, введенное число сохраняется в переменной, после чего текстовое поле вновь заменяется ссылкой с новым значением (которое было сохранено в переменной).
- если текстовое поле теряет фокус по другой причине (не по нажатию на клавишу enter), например: переход к другой ссылке, событие click по body и т.д., или новое значение не введено и нажата клавиша enter, **необходимо сделать так, чтобы вернулась ссылка, со своим первоначальным текстом.**

Первые две задачи выполнены, проблема в третьей. [**Вот код**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/xpWa3/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замечу, что у вас не совсем верно построена последовательность. Не нужно никуда девать ссылку, пусть она останется, просто скройте её "display: none" (или hide в jquery), это избавит вас и фреймворк от лишних забот. Достаточно будет изменять необходимый атрибут, при сохранении поля ввода. Нужное вам событие называется blur.

```
$(input).blur(function(){ restoreLink(); })
```

Comment: istem, спасибо. 

Если не сложно, не могли бы ли Вы ответить еще на один вопрос: http://hashcode.ru/questions/157489/jquery-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F